# .save is not a function and .map is not a function while updating document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have below code: When I try to from postman it says :

> "message": "account.save is not a function"

```
const account = await Account.find({ "buildings.gateways.devices.verificationCode": code })
    var accountId = account ? account.map(item => item._id) : null

const buildings = _.flatMap(account, a => a.buildings)
const gateways = _.flatMap(buildings, b => b.gateways);
const devices = _.flatMap(gateways, g => g.devices);

// finding deviceId to insert for user from that account
const device = _.filter(devices, d => d.verificationCode === code);

device.patientFirstName = req.body.firstName;
device.patientLastName = req.body.lastName;
account.save();
```

If I try to change to findOne() then it says

> "account.map is not a function"

account always returns values then why it cant map i dont understand.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` returns an array so you're able to run [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but you need to `.save()` each document separately:

```
const accounts = await Account.find({ "buildings.gateways.devices.verificationCode": code })
var accountId = account ? account.map(item => item._id) : null

for(let account of accounts){
    await account.save();
}
```

`.findOne()` (awaited) returns single document so you cannot use `.map()`:

```
const account = await Account.findOne({ "buildings.gateways.devices.verificationCode": code })
var accountId = account ? account._id : null

account.save();
```